# Clash of Clans Difficult village transfer

Tags: iphone, clash-of-clans

I first started playing clash of clans on my iPod 4th generation.  I soon realized I wanted to start over because I upgraded too quickly and wasted gems.  I started over and my new village (lvl 65) is much better than the old village (lvl 50).  I recently got an iPhone 5c and want to transfer my lvl 65 village over.  I have tried but only my lvl 50 village will transfer.  What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We have so many related COC questions, that could you edit in a bit how you got two accounts in game center. Also, the vendor provides step by step instructions on village transfer, so linking to some instructions COC support and explain how the best article you found isn't making sense might help us if the normal steps aren't working. We'll gladly reopen this once it's more clear what your sticking point is if we don't have multiple answer that cover your situation already.

Answer (score 1):

Clash of Clans is designed so that a user can have only one CoC account associated with an Apple ID.

There are multiple ways to start over in the game. You can delete the app and restall and then not continue the game when prompted or you can create a new Apple ID and start a new account on it.

If you deleted the app and started over, you shouldn't be able to transfer the account to a new device. If you used a different Apple ID then just login with it.

If this doesn't help you you can send Supercell a support ticket or an email and they will help you.